# Community awarded bounty?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I've seen a few questions, including [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/what-actually-happens-when-you-swipe-an-app-out-of-the-recent-apps-list/20465#20465) one, that have a bounty awarded (often large) to a non-accepted and usually not top answer, by [Community](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). These seem somewhat arbitrary, as the answer referenced does not seem to be particularly well suited to the question.

Are these just random rep-boosters? I'm assuming they serve some larger purpose?

Just curious. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Community will auto-award bounties 24 hours after their expiration under the following criteria:

> Twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty
>   starter has not manually awarded the bounty, an eligible answer can be
>   automatically awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an
>   answer to be eligible for automatic awarding are as follows:
>
> - The answer must be given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must
>     have a score of at least +2
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the
>   same score, the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.

So the timeline is:

1. Bounty is offered
2. Answer is posted and voted up to at least +2
3. Bounty period (and 24 hour grace period) expires without the user who offered it awarding the bounty to anyone
4. Community auto-awards half of the bounty to the answer from #2 above

Additional info can be found on MSO in [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)